# async await code executing not as expected

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I created a simple example to understand async/await in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = BarAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
    }

    private static async Task BarAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This happens before await");
        int i = await QuxAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("This happens after await. This result of await is " + i);
    }

    private static Task<int> QuxAsync()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            c++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("in the middle processing...");
        return Task.FromResult(c);
    }
}
```

So the program prints `This happens before await` first then count the value from a return method. Afterwards it prints the result.

[image]

It looks good. My question is that since await doesn't block the thread that evaluates the async method. My understanding is if the async takes a long time it will return to its calling method.

For my example, because QuxAsync() takes a long time, the code

```
Console.WriteLine("Main");
```

is not blocked and will be evaluated very soon. 
I think the print order should be

```
 This happens before await
 Main
 in the middle processing...
 This happens after await. This result of await is 2147483647
```

However it is not, why?

Comment: Nothing in `QuxAsync` is _actually_ async, just because it is marked as such, doesn't make it async. Your operations run synchronously, that's why the printing order is the way it is.

Comment: I can't explain this exact reason that you're asking but I can explain a scenario for `WebApi's` I still have a vague understanding of running `await / async` code in a console application as I don't have to do it often. When I did I would use `Task.Result()` to get the result. Anyway, the `await Task<T>` will allow the current thread execution to be released back into the thread pool and let another thread use it, once the work is done, the task scheduler then assigns the same thread or an available thread if `.ConfigureAwait(false)` is used and continue's the work. It does block the thread

Comment: `async` doesn't mean parallel, and `Task` doesn't mean threads. Leaning by creating examples is great, however if you have to ask a question for everything that doesnt happen the way you would imagine, you are going down a long and painful road, i would suggest researching `async and await` a lot more first. go through stackoverflow and check out all the async and await tag/questions and answers. Check out Stephen Clearys and Stephen Toubs blogs

Comment: @MickyD: Concurrency and asynchrony are not the same thing; an asynchronous workflow need not be concurrent. Consider for example the workflow "beep the horn, then asynchronously wait one second, then open the door", and a message arrives during the asynchronous wait that can be processed in 10 milliseconds. You don't need a second worker thread to implement this asynchronous flow.

Comment: @Hello: Experimenting is a good idea, particularly since it is demonstrating that you have some wrong ideas about asynchrony. This is a good opportunity to get correct beliefs. I second the suggestion above that you do more reading first. I also would add to that suggestion **do your experiments in a GUI app**.  Console applications have an unusual threading context for asynchronous workflows that can be confusing. GUI applications make it much easier to see how asynchronous workflows can be achieved with a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll second (third?) others' recommendations that you continue reading and learning about `async`. I'm partial to my own [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), but these days there are a number of good ones out there.

> My question is that since await doesn't block the thread that evaluates the async method. My understanding is if the async takes a long time it will return to its calling method.

This is the part that is wrong. Asynchrony has absolutely nothing to do with how long something takes.

There's two pieces of knowledge missing, both covered in my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

First: `await` works by first checking its argument. If it is already completed, then `await` continues executing - *synchronously*.

Second: every method is called synchronously. Including `async` methods. The only time asynchrony happens is when an `async` method has an `await` whose argument is *not* already completed; in that case, that `async` method returns an incomplete task.

Putting both of these together should explain why your code actually runs synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will read your info. But before that how do I know the argument is completed or not in my case?

Comment: @Hello: `Task.FromResult` returns a completed task.

Comment: Under the hood, a state machine was generated. In the `MoveNext` method of the struct, `TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted` was used for returning or not. I assume the first argument for the await is it.
I don't know how Task complected is connected to this argument(`TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted`)?

Comment: @Hello: Yes, a state machine is generated for `BarAsync`. When the first state of that state machine is executed, the code in `BarAsync` runs, including the call to `QuxAsync` and getting its return value (`Task.FromResult`). The state machine (as part of the `await`) then examines whether the task is completed (it is), so it continues executing, returning a completed task from `BarAsync`.